# Did Christian "Chris" Wolff know Braxton's whereabouts?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-accountant

In the movie [The Accountant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Accountant_(2016_film)), was Chris (Ben Affleck) always aware of the whereabouts of Braxton (Jon Bernthal)?

Chris attacked and killed most of the guards at Lamar Blackburn's house.
Chris said to Braxton he can find him and he kept him away to keep him safe from his clients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes he knows the whereabouts of Braxton. But he didn't know he would find him in Lamar's house.

He just doesn't want to get him involved in his life. By whereabouts, he would have been keeping the check on his brother, whether he is doing fine or not. Which is why when Braxton asked him "How will I find you?" (after Chris shows interest in meeting in a week), Chris replied: "You won't. I'll find you".